# POST method in Spring does not accept application / json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

In a Spring api, I have a method in a RestController for POST requests, however, when the request is made by Postman the system returns error 415:

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-07-02T18:08:48.859+0000",
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
"path": "/api/call"
}
```

RestController class:

```
@RestController("/api/call")
public class CallController {

    private final MailService mailService;

    public CallController(MailService mailService) {
        super();
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> postCall(@Valid @RequestBody Email formEmail) throws URISyntaxException {
        mailService.sendMail();

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

}
```

Email class:

```
public class Email {

    private static String MAIL_TO = "mail@email.com";

    @Null
    private String mailTo;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3)
    private String nameUserRequest;

    @NotNull
    @javax.validation.constraints.Email
    private String emailUserRequest;


    @NotNull
    private String text;

    public Email() {
        super();
    }

    public String getMailTo() {
        mailTo = MAIL_TO;
        return mailTo;
    }

    public void setMailTo(String mailTo) {
        this.mailTo = mailTo;
    }

    public String getNameUserRequest() {
        return nameUserRequest;
    }

    public void setNameUserRequest(String nameUserRequest) {
        this.nameUserRequest = nameUserRequest;
    }

    public String getEmailUserRequest() {
        return emailUserRequest;
    }

    public void setEmailUserRequest(String emailUserRequest) {
        this.emailUserRequest = emailUserRequest;
    }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Email [nameUserRequest=" + nameUserRequest + ", emailUserRequest=" + emailUserRequest + ", text=" + text
                + "]";
    }


}
```

Postman request:

[image]

The purpose is that the Post method only receives a Json for Email and returns success after sending the email, but it returns error 415, I tried `@PostMapping(consumes ="application/json", produces="application/json")` but it did not work. What is left for the system to accept Json requests?

**Edited**

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company.mail.call</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail-call</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>mail-call</name>
    <description>Mail call</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: How did you set up your application; is it a boilerplate Initializr project? Can you include your POM? (As notes: You never need to explicitly call `super()` and can drop your `Email` constructor entirely. If you know that you're wanting to return a No Content you can make your method `void` and annotate `@ResponseStatus(NO_CONTENT)`. Finally, I suggest naming your class `EmailForm` or `EmailDto`, because the simple name `Email` is used a lot, including the Hibernate `@Email` annotation you probably want to use in that class.)

Comment: Can you try to add `@PostMapping(value= "", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)`? Have you changed the Jackson configuration?

Comment: did you put `content-type=application;json` in postman headers?

Comment: I added the pom.xml in question. About Jackson, I did not configure, I'm actually starting to see something about it now, do I need it to run Json on the requisitions?

Comment: @dehasi Yes, I added application/json in the Header.

Comment: can you use raw with JSON in postman body section ?

Comment: You're right @chrylis! My Email class caused the problem because it ended up importing the email validation :( Now it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should define the `@RequestMapping("/api/call")` on top of class to enable your route. `@RestController("/api/call")` that value inside `@RestController` defines the component name that will be managed by the Spring.